# Migrating PHP4 to 5 and handling Exceptions

Tags: php, exception, legacy

I'm migrating a legacy app from PHP4 to PHP5.2, and one of the libraries it uses is now throwing exceptions which cause the scripts to break. Am I correct in thinking that under PHP4 this exception wouldn't be handled in the same way (i.e. not at all) and so the script would just continue on from the point the exception is now thrown? Is there any way to restore this behaviour under PHP5 (ideally just for the pages where the library is included)? The exception in question is a com_exception from a library dealing with Excel.

Comment: Please add either example code and the full exception message or/and add more information on which OS you are and what PHP versions you use exactly!

Comment: off topic, but why 5.2? why not go to straight PHP5.3, since that's the latest mature version? (it's got a few nice features that 5.2 is missing)

Comment: Several features (most noticeably the ereg regex functions) are deprecated in 5.3 and are used extensively throughout the project, meaning a lot of warnings are emitted. Once we've migrated to 5.2 the migration to 5.3 should be easier and can be done at a later date.

Comment: fair enough; that's a good reason. I'd certainly suggest converting your `ereg` to `preg` functions sooner rather than later though; it's not actually that hard to do (just a bit time consuming, I guess, if you've got lots of them).

Comment: It's already on the list of things to do :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all binary PHP distributions for Windows that I found from 5.1.2 to 5.1.3 (cvs also) and i had to handle the exception.

My PHP setup is the typical one described in 'install.txt' of the PHP
package. The only change that I have made in php.ini (except of the
doc_root) is 'com.allow_dcom = true'.

so u will have to use

```
catch( com_exception $e )
{
print( $e->__toString( ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 4 didn't support exceptions at all. The syntax to throw an exception would have been invalid syntax in PHP 4. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

It would be handy to have been told a bit more about the class that is throwing the exeption.

My guess is that there's a bugm either in the class itself or in the way you're calling it which was being triggered all along and was being ignored, but is now causing this exception to be thrown.

This page is about the changes in PHP5, and has some insights into how the com_exception works: http://devzone.zend.com/article/762

To quote:

> PHP 5 introduces structured exception handling (try, catch() and throw()) and this allows us to expose the underlying COM exceptions to PHP using the built-in com_exception class. If you want to catch errors in your scripts, you might write code like this:

```
<?php
$com = new COM("...");
try {
  $com->call_a_method();
}
catch (com_exception $e) {
  print $e . "\n";
}
?>
```

I hope the above code snippet helps you. Printing the error message may (should) reveal more about what exactly is going wrong, which should help you work out where to go from there.

It is possible, of course, that the Excel class you're using may also need to be upgraded; if it was part of your old PHP4 app, then presumably it's quite an old class; there may be a newer version of it available, and if you have found a bug in the class, then a new version may deal with that.

Comment: I'm not sure that more detail on the class will help - I'm guessing there is a bug in the library (there could be loads, it's from 2000 and isn't tested against current versions of Office), I just wondered if there was a way to make PHP behave in the same way under 5.2 as under 4 w.r.t. exceptions (clearly not a long term solution but there is a time pressure on this)

Comment: if the bug isn't breaking anything, then just use `try` / `catch` with nothing in the `catch` block. That will allow your code to carry on past the error. But what it won't do is fix the error, so if there is actually a problem in the class itself then I can't help. (hence I suggest checking for new versions... or even an alternative product)